# Item characteristic curves in R ltm: any way to swap line style for default color?

Tags: r

I have conducted an IRT analysis using package ltm in R 3.41. In plotting the curves using the plot command, the default is to use colors for the lines of the items. Unfortunately, I need to use a scheme that differentiates item lines using a line type, not color (journal where figure will be published will only publish black/white for free). Is it possible to tweak this using the native ltm plot command?

Comment: Hard without example code. Just try `plot(yourModel, col = 'black', lty = 1:8)`. Works with the basic `ltm` example inside the documentation.

Comment: Brilliant! It's a bit hard to discern the line types, but it will absolutely do! Thanks!

Comment: To follow-up, is it possible to make each line have a different symbol delineating the points (i.e., circles, diamonds, triangles) while remaining black? or is the default lty the simplest.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A combination of `lty` and `pch` for each line (try the same with `pch`) ?

Comment: Thanks again @MartinSchmelzer. This code below achieves what I need after playing with it a bit.

plot(yourModel, zrange=c(-15.0, 15.0), items=c(2,3,5,7), col='black', pch=11:14, lwd=1.5, legend=TRUE, cex = 1.0, xlab="YourModelLabel")